# update pivot table using foreach loop with dynamic form input

Tags: arrays, laravel, dynamic, foreach, pivot-table

Please check this image you will get idea what i need  [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByoLPyyQ3jAjalNHSFN4R3ZoMUE/view?usp=sharing)
i want insert many flight to one transport but i want select persons for transports and flights everything working perfect 
but  for the flight details  if i select two persons in first flight two person in second flight in my pivot table its upadating  4 persons name in both flight deatils.  check this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByoLPyyQ3jAjSkdpMlR3NlBpNDg/view?usp=sharing)

i want insert persons name separte like first flight deatils two persons and second flight details two persons
so this is my controller

```
$data = array();
        $origin = $request->get('origin');
        $destination = $request->get('destination');
        $flight_no = $request->flight_no;
        $dep_date = $request->dep_date;
        $arrival_date = $request->arrival_date;
        foreach ($origin as $key => $value){
            $data[] = [
                'transport_id' => $new->id,
                'origin' => $value,
                'destination' =>$destination[$key],
                'flight_no' =>$flight_no[$key],
                'dep_date' =>Carbon::parse($dep_date[$key])->format('Y-m-d h:i'),
                'arrival_date'=> Carbon::parse($arrival_date[$key])->format('Y-m-d h:i'),
                'user_id'=> Auth::id()
            ];
        }

        foreach($data as $d){
            $flight = Flight::create($d);
            $flight->crews()->attach($request->input('flight_crew_list'));
        }
```

how can i ? if not clear what you need to help me ?
EDIT :
My form like this im adding dynamic flight form using VueJs

```
<tr v-for="row in rows">

<td>

    <ul>
        @foreach($crew_id as $key => $name)
          <li> {!! Form::checkbox('flight_crew_list[]', $key) !!}
           <b> {!! strtoupper($name) !!} </b>: ({{ $crew_type[$key] }})</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</td>

<td>
    <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('origin', 'Origin',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::text('origin[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm text-upper',]) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('destination', 'Destination',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::text('destination[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm text-upper']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('flight_no', 'Flight No',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::text('flight_no[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm text-upper']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('datetime3', 'Departure',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::text('dep_date[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','id'=>'datetime3']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            {!! Form::label('datetime4', 'Arrival Date',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {!! Form::text('arrival_date[]',null,['class' => 'input-field input-sm','id'=>'datetime4']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <a @click="removeRow(row)">
    <button class="btn btn-xs " type="button" id="dim">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
    </button>
    </a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how your input form is made and what exactly arrives in the input('flight_crew_list').

My guess is that input('flight_crew_list') contains all Crew members IDs selected in the entire form, that explains why you have all 4 crew members assigned for a single flight.

If you want more details please post the source code of the form you attached in the first picture.

upd:

As i suspected the problem lays here:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('flight_crew_list[]', $key) !!}
```

You are generating unique array flight_crew_list that contains all elements checked in the form. However what you need is for every flight keep an array of checked crew members:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('flight_crew_list[' . $row_id ']', $key) !!}
```

So after in back-end you can attach only values that was checked for this specific flight.

```
foreach($data as $index => $d){
    $flight = Flight::create($d);
    $flight->crews()->attach($request->input('flight_crew_list[' . $index . ']'));
}
```

Comment: hey thnks but im adding rows using **vue-js** im facing problem to pass that **$row_id**

Comment: i know how to get $row_id  like this  `@{{  $index }}`  i can get the id but how to pass? any idea ?

Comment: In the back-end you're iterating for every origin, so technically you already have $row_id on the back-end. You don't need to pass anything.